# How to make discord.js bot reply to DM but only once

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot reply to any DM it was sent with a specific message but only once so if it was dmed again by the same user it would ignore it.

This is my code 
But right now it keeps sending the message if they keep dming I have no clue how to confront this

```
  if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
    msg.author.send("test");
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: You could just save the IDs of the users who the bot has received a DM from. And when the bot gets a DM just check if the user id is already in the saved id's. If it is, then do nothing, if not, send the message. It won't be the perfect solution, but it would work for a while

Answer (score 0):

You could save the IDs like Alan suggested but you don't really need to

```js
if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
    if (msg.author.dmChannel.lastMessage) return;
    //code
}
```